# How to write a bash function that can detect if a given input ends in Kilobytes `K` or Megabytes `M`?

Tags: bash

I have a bash function that is currently set up as:

```
MB=$(( $(echo $(FUNCTION_THAT_RETURNS_Kb_OR_Mb) | cut -d "K" -f 1 | sed 's/^.*- //') / 1000 ))
```

where the middle portion `echo $(FUNCTION_THAT_RETURNS_Kb_OR_Mb)` returns a value that ends in `K` or `M`, (for example: `515223 K` or `36326 M`) for Kilobytes or Megabytes. I currently have designed the function to strip the trailing units indicator for `K`, and then divide by 1000 to convert to megabytes. However, when the inside part of it ends in `M`, it fails. How can I write a function that detects if its in kilobytes or megabytes?

Comment: What's the use of `sed 's/^.*- //'` there?

Comment: There is `numfmt`

Comment: @oguzismail he's deleting all characters followed by ```- ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel - there is `numfmt`:

```
function_that_returns_Kb_or_Mb() { echo "515223 K"; }
mb=$(function_that_returns_Kb_or_Mb | numfmt -d '' --from=iec --to-unit=Mi)
# mb=504
function_that_returns_Kb_or_Mb() { echo "36326 M"; }
mb=$(function_that_returns_Kb_or_Mb | numfmt -d '' --from=iec --to-unit=Mi)
# mb=36326
```

Notes:

- `echo $(FUNCTION_THAT_RETURNS_Kb_OR_Mb)` is a useless use of `echo`. It's like `echo $(echo $(echo $(...))))`. Just `FUNCTION_THAT_RETURNS_Kb_OR_Mb | blabla`.
- By convention UPPERCASE VARIABLES are used for exported variables, like `PATH` `COLUMNS` `UID` `PWD` etc. - use lower case identifiers in your scripts.
- I assumed input and output is using IEC scale, for SI scale use `--from=si --to-unit=M`.